# Failure to query User private repo data from Github API v3

Tags: ajax, github, github-api

I'm trying to access my own private Github repository data via the Github v3 API. I can't seem to access my private repo data, only public.

The following details the basic AJAX call I am running:

`$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.github.com/users/' + userName + '/repos?visibility=private',
  // url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/' + orgName + '/repos?type=private',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'token ' + auth
  }
})`

Where `auth` is defined and authenticates successfully (I have a token for Org & token for User - both authenticate successfully), and where `userName` and `orgName` are both also valid.

Console output for Org access includes only private repositories, as declared in the `url` queryString.

Console output for User access includes only public repositories, contradictory to the `url` queryString. I have also tried `type=private` as opposed to `visibility=private` - neither return only private results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That API endpoint will return public repositories only (regardless of authentication), as documented here:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories

You need to use a different endpoint to fetch private repositories for the authenticated user:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories

If you're using a token to authenticate, the token needs to have `repo` scope:

https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes

Comment: ivan-zuzak & @jack-ryan I've combined my two examples you helped me through into a repo here: https://github.com/davewallace/api-specimen  if you're interested in contributing then by all means, please do. Figured it might be useful to have something consolidated, though I can mostly tackle only front-end.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `GET` request should be hitting `https://api.github.com/' + userName + '/repos'`, after a look at the [GitHub API docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/). Note this should return all public and private repositories, but you can use the visibility flag as you stated in your question to resolve that.

Comment: Thanks @jack-ryan I did try that alternative, but that returns a 404, where using /users/userName/repos at least returns public repos.

Comment: I feel like the issue could potentially be with your authentication then, because /users/UserName/repos will only ever return public repositories. It requires no authentication.

Comment: When I use an incorrect token for auth, it correctly fails, and using the correct token it returns public data. Is this a valid test for auth do you think?

Comment: From the GitHub API authentication pages: "Typically, we send a 404 error when your client isn't properly authenticated. You might expect to see a 403 Forbidden in these cases. However, since we don't want to provide any information about private repositories, the API returns a 404 error instead."

Comment: Update: I am trying to do some simple curl requests and noticing a similar issue, only returning public repositories even with proper authentication. Will continue to look into it.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help!

Comment: I am wondering if their API is having issues, I have tried with 2 separate authentication methods and still receive 404 with the standard /user/repos GET.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115776/discussion-between-danjah-and-jack-ryan).